# MySQl permission error in ZabbixAgent

Tags: mysql, agent, zabbix

I have seperated zabbix server and agent. I want to monitor mysql status. I finished the setup steps, so zabbix agent wasalready enabled. But still got mysql status down and when I check the agent log file I got an error such as

```
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysq/mysql.sock' (13)'
Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' exists!
4932:20160118:201903.278 In zbx_waitpid()
4932:20160118:201903.278 zbx_waitpid() exited, status:1
4932:20160118:201903.278 End of zbx_waitpid():4941
4932:20160118:201903.278 Run remote command [HOME=/var/lib/zabbix/mysqladmin ping | grep -c alive] Result [1] [0]...
4932:20160118:201903.278 Sending back [0]
4932:20160118:201903.278 listener #2 [waiting for connection]
496:20160118:201904.013 In send_buffer() host:'xx.xx.xx.xxx' port:10051 values:0/100
4936:20160118:201904.013 End of send_buffer():SUCCEED
4936:20160118:201904.013 active checks #1 [idle 1 sec]
```

Otherwise I gave some privileges to zabbix user such as

```
mysql -uzabbix -p -e"GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'zabbix'@'127.0.0.1' IDENTIFIED BY '123456'";
mysql -uroot -p -e"GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'zabbix'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '123456'";
```

and even got reply when I run mysql status command. What am I missing in setup stage?

Comment: Are you sure that the service `myslqd` is running on localhost?

Comment: **Of course** and that's status log.
`Jan 18 19:55:17 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
Jan 18 19:55:17 localhost.localdomain mysqld_safe[4330]: 160118 19:55:17 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysqld.log'.
Jan 18 19:55:17 localhost.localdomain mysqld_safe[4330]: 160118 19:55:17 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
Jan 18 19:55:18 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started MySQL Community Server.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
`

Comment: That's mysqld status in DB Server
`
ls -l /var/run/ | grep mysqld
drwxr-xr-x.  2 mysql  mysql    60 Jan 18 19:55 mysqld`

Comment: Send your zabbix_agentd.conf (that was installed in your database server.

Comment: mysqld service worked right now but still don't get result with **zabbix agent**